# Set Environment variables on Engine Yard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, production, engineyard

My app is on Engine Yard services and I need to set the environment variables to work with my secret id and password.

Somebody know how I can set each variables? What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've just managed to set environment variables for my application running on Unicorn.

1. Open /data/{app_name}/shared/config/env.custom and edit it to look like this:

   ```
   export SECRET_ID=yourid
   export SECRET_PASSWORD=yourpass
   ```
2. Restart unicorn `/engineyard/bin/app_{app_name} reload`

If you are using passenger take a look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12955526/1520775
https://github.com/jimneath/ey-cloud-recipes/tree/master/cookbooks/passenger_env_vars

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Unicorn, you can try putting them in /data//shared/config/env.custom. Otherwise, it can be tricky.  Throw in a Support ticket and they'll have a look.

Disclosure: I work there :)