# How to handle secrets.yml in Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am using Rails 4.1's secrets.yml to store my keys etc, but I am wondering, if this file should be gitignore, so I don't store any sensitive data in my repo?

If I gitignore it, how do I access secrets on my server? (Which is Engineyard, in this case)

Answer (score 1):

You should use envirement-variablesand set them on the production-system.

```
key: <%= ENV['PRODUCTION_KEY'] %>
```

I don´t know Engineyard, but on heroku there are some simple commands to set the envirement-variables

```
heroku config:add PRODUCTION_KEY=123
```

@Update, here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824509/set-enviroment-variables-on-engine-yard) on stackoverflow on how you set them on engineyard

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer because using ENV variables is the standard practice among most professionals (opinion I know, but one shared among many leading developers).